# Is there a way to get the explore feed of instagram by a query using python?

Tags: python, api, instagram, libraries, instagram-graph-api

I have been searching online and I was able to get posts by hashtags and posts of my on explore page. However, is there a way I can enter a query. For example, Paris and get the explore page of the word Paris(so it would be a mix of the location Paris, hashtag Paris and Instagram's own recommendation) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The link to search for hashtags is:

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/HASHTAGHERE/
```

What you can do is try to curl the site via python and download the pictures  ( which I don't know if you want it )

Also you can create a new instagram account, follow all the hashtags you want, login and then get the feed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am able to get hashtags using the instagramy library, is there a way I can get location as well to imitate the Top explore page[when you enter Paris, you get a mix of the paris  hashtag and the paris location]